# Django template: context for loop traversal

Tags: python, django, for-loop, data-structures, django-templates

I am working of a context of this strucutre:

```
{
  data:{
         0000:{ "name": "foo"  , "start": 0,   "end":900}
         1111:{ "name": "foo2" , "start": 23,  "end":330}
         2222:{ "name": "foo3" , "start": 430, "end":90}
       }
}
```

on the template:

```
<p> {{ data.0000 }} </p>
```

will output everything (name, start, end) to the html file

if I attempt to loop through the structure:

```
{% for route in data %}
    <p> {{route}} </p>
    {% for attribute in route %}
    <p> {{attribute}} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

it will not output anything

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: Loop through `for id, route in data.items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would do:

```
{% for route, values in data.items %}
    <p> {{route}} </p>
    {% for k, v in values.items %}
        <p> {{k}} : {{v}} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

assuming, from the view, you send this dictionary with the name `'data'` in the context.

```
data = {
  data:{
         0000:{ "name": "foo"  , "start": 0,   "end":900}
         1111:{ "name": "foo2" , "start": 23,  "end":330}
         2222:{ "name": "foo3" , "start": 430, "end":90}
       }
}
```

Comment: data meant to be a string?